# unable to subset data frame based on two different values in loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I would like to subset so that it has the latest data. I have to do this this way so that I can insert the df to the db in one shot. My Data frame looks like this:

```
dput(pp)
structure(list(DATE_TIME = structure(c(1369320180, 1369321980, 
1369323780, 1369325580, 1369327380, 1369285980, 1369287780, 1369289580, 
1369291380, 1369293180, 1369294980, 1369296780, 1369298580, 1369300380, 
1369302180, 1369303980, 1369305780, 1369307580, 1369309380, 1369311180
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SITE = c("Home Page Login", 
"Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", 
"Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", 
"Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", 
"Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", 
"Home Page Login", "Home Page Login", "Home Page Login"), RESPONSE_TIME = c("0.728", 
"0.513", "0.308", "0.432", "0.877", "0.541", "0.736", "0.333", 
"0.354", "0.279", "0.178", "0.699", "0.583", "-", "0.372", "0.972", 
"1.066", "0.550", "0.246", "0.299"), AVAIL_PERCENT = c("100.00", 
"100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", 
"100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "-", "100.00", 
"100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00", "100.00"), AGENT = c(42627, 
42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 
42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 
42627)), .Names = c("DATE_TIME", "SITE", "RESPONSE_TIME", "AVAIL_PERCENT", 
"AGENT"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have build a function that takes the name of the data frame as a parameter, goes though the data frame one agent and one site at a time, goes the data base retrieves latest time stamp, and subsets the data frame. The final data frame will be inserted to the db. My function is as follows:

```
normal<-function(x) {
    x<-unique(x)
    pagelist<-unique(x$SITE)
    agentlist<-unique(x$AGENT)
    latest<-data.frame(DATE_TIME=as.POSIXct(character()), SITE=character(), RESPONSE_TIME=as.numeric(character()), AVAIL_PERCENT=as.numeric(character()), AGENT=as.numeric(character()))
for(j in 1:length(agentlist)){  
    new<-subset(x, AGENT==agentlist[j])
    for(i in 1:length(pagelist)) {

        sql1<-c("SELECT max(T.DATE_TIME) FROM <TABLE NAME> T where T.SITE=")
        sql2<-pagelist[i]
        sql<-paste(sql1, sql2, sep="'")
        sql<-gsub("\\Z","'", sql, perl=T)

        sql<-paste(sql, "and T.AGENT=", sep=" ")
        sql<-paste(sql, agentlist[j], sep="'")
        sql<-gsub("\\Z","'", sql, perl=T)
        print(sql)
        ch=odbcConnect("<userid>",pwd = "<passwd>")
        latest_date<-sqlQuery(ch, sql)
        odbcClose(ch)
        latest_date<-latest_date[1,1]
        new1<-subset(new, SITE==pagelist[i] & DATE_TIME > latest_date)
        latest<-rbind(new1, latest)
        print(head(latest,5))
        return(latest)
    }
}
}
```

when I do this:

df<-normal(pp)

I only get one site and one agent. The final df should have all agents for each site. Any ideas what am I doing here wrong?

Comment: Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop...?

Comment: @joran, simple things like that, thank you. I really stared at this a quite some time.

Comment: FWIW, there's no real need to open and close the ODBC connection each time through the for loop either. Also, don't be surprised if you run into performance problems with your strategy of `rbind`ing things together like that.

Comment: @joran, I have another question that I cannot figure it out, can I change the post on this one or ask a new question?

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question. (And you should just write up the answer for this one yourself, and accept it. That way everyone knows it was resolved, and you get rep! ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I had to put the return statment outside of the loops.

```
normal<-function(x) {
        x<-unique(x)
        pagelist<-unique(x$SITE)
        agentlist<-unique(x$AGENT)
        latest<-data.frame(DATE_TIME=as.POSIXct(character()), SITE=character(), RESPONSE_TIME=as.numeric(character()), AVAIL_PERCENT=as.numeric(character()), AGENT=as.numeric(character()))
    for(j in 1:length(agentlist)){  
        new<-subset(x, AGENT==agentlist[j])
        for(i in 1:length(pagelist)) {

            sql1<-c("SELECT max(T.DATE_TIME) FROM <TABLE NAME> T where T.SITE=")
            sql2<-pagelist[i]
            sql<-paste(sql1, sql2, sep="'")
            sql<-gsub("\\Z","'", sql, perl=T)

            sql<-paste(sql, "and T.AGENT=", sep=" ")
            sql<-paste(sql, agentlist[j], sep="'")
            sql<-gsub("\\Z","'", sql, perl=T)
            print(sql)
            ch=odbcConnect("<userid>",pwd = "<passwd>")
            latest_date<-sqlQuery(ch, sql)
            odbcClose(ch)
            latest_date<-latest_date[1,1]
            new1<-subset(new, SITE==pagelist[i] & DATE_TIME > latest_date)
            latest<-rbind(new1, latest)
            print(head(latest,5))
                }
    }
    return(latest)

    }
```